# how to access div inside props like avatar, actions of cardheader(child of card element from materialUI) div using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to write test cases for a react js class using Jest and Enzyme frameworks.My react class uses **Card** class in material UI. Part of my code looks like this .

```
<Card>
     <CardHeader
        avatar = {<div className={classes.imgHolder}><img src='/opt/imgs.png'/></div>} 
        actions = {<div/>}
        title = {<div/>}
      />
</Card>
```

Part of my test code looks like this.

```
let  wrapper=shallow(<PlainHeader {...props}/>).dive();
let header_ = wrapper.find('WithStyles(CardHeader)'
```

So my question here is , how do I access div inside avatar prop or check if there is a node  existed in the avatar using any enzyme methods like **find** ?
`wrapper.find('WithStyles(CardHeader)').props().avatar.prop('img')` did not work.

I do not find any references in web for such question.

Have browsed many links and have tried many airbnb enzyme functions but that gives errors.

Comment: I can't understand what you want . Can you please elaborate What you want.??

Comment: @AnkitVerma  I've edited my question. Please check and let me know if it is clear or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing a component that renders `CardHeader` I would only check in those tests that the component is passing the right props to `CardHeader`, not that `CardHeader` is really rendering them (I would test that in the tests for `CardHeader`).

So, a test to check that `CardHeader` is indeed receiving the right props would look like:

```
const  wrapper = shallow(<PlainHeader {...props} />);
expect(wrapper.find(CardHeader).props().avatar).toEqual(<div><img src='/opt/imgs.png'/></div>)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . How would I check only the <img> tag of the avatar.

Comment: I figured out how to do this . I have assigned an id to img and tried getting it using id .
`wrapper.find('#imgID')`